# how to use grep command in file handling

Tags: perl

Am very new to Perl,

My requirement is read one directory and search or match for particular file and handle read that file

I know its very easy to you people but i cannot do that so please give some guidance to complete this

i have listed by code below.

{

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::stat;
use File::Copy;
use Sys::Hostname;

$source_raw_directory = "/dfactory/data/raw/in/";

opendir (DIR,$source_raw_directory) 

#foreach @array (grep(/hiea_._DeletedPatient\.txt$/,readdir(DIR)));
@array = grep (/\hiea_._DeletedPatient\.txt$/,readdir(DIR))
    #print "@array"; 
closedir(DIR);
```

}
am getting error like below

"Array found where operator expected at Deleted_Patient.pl line 45, at end of line
        (Missing operator before ?)
syntax error at Deleted_Patient.pl line 45, near ")

```
    #foreach @array (grep(/hiea_._DeletedPatient\.txt$/,readdir(DIR)));
     @array "
```

Deleted_Patient.pl had compilation errors"

Thanks
pandia

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't. I find `opendir` and `grep` a clunky idiom to be using when you can `glob` instead.

```
foreach my $filename ( glob ( "$source_raw_directory/*iea_._DeletedPatient.txt" ) ) {
    print $filename,"\n";
}
```

Note - glob expands the path, so you'll have full path names. I usually consider that an advantage, because it means you don't ever forget to include the pathname with `open` calls.

Answer (score 0):

You say your error includes " (Missing operator before ?)". That's not particularly clear, but it seems to imply that the error comes before the code quoted in the error. The line before `@array` is a comment, so that's unlikely to be the problem, so let's look at the line before that.

```
opendir (DIR,$source_raw_directory)
```

I think it's clear what the problem is. There's no comment at the end of the line.

I tested your code using Perl 5.22.2, which gives the far clearer error message:

> Array found where operator expected at test line 13, near ")
>
> ```
> #foreach @array (grep(/hiea_._DeletedPatient\.txt$/,readdir(DIR)));
> @array"
> ```
>
> (Missing semicolon on previous line?)

Answer (score -1):

For first, use google and official POD document, as example 
http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html

And your code worked with this:

```
$source_raw_directory = "/dfactory/data/raw/in/";

opendir(my $dh, $source_raw_directory) || die "Can't opendir $source_raw_directory: $!";
my @dots = grep { /\hiea_._DeletedPatient\.txt$/ } readdir($dh);
closedir $dh;
```

Comment: And, if you use "strict", you must set notice for all your vars (my @array = ...)

Comment: @PANDIALAKSHMANAN what you need in final result?